# Read the database in linq to sql before submit

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I want insert/ update some items in the database with linq, but not submit it yet before the user is sure he wants keep the changes he made.

in the mean time I need that all the query I do to the database will give me the modifided data, (like transaction read uncommited)

How can I do it? I tried just use a transaction. but it's not working with linq.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is not going to happen out of the box with Linq-2-sql. The datacontext will not return your 'pending inserts' until you call `SubmitChanges()`.

I guess you could insert them with a flag that allows you to delete them or finalize them depending on the final decision of the user.

By the way: transactions do work in Linq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386995(v=vs.100).aspx